# How to investigate differences in performance between logically equivalent Scala functions?

Tags: scala, performance, jvm

Using Scala 2.12, I am using the following, equivalent two codes:

```
  def isSimilarFast(s1: Point, s2: Point): Boolean = {
    Haversine.distance(s1.lat, s1.lon, s2.lat, s2.lon) <= 5.0 &&
    Levenshtein.distance(s1.label, s2.label) <= 2
  }

  def isSimilarSlow(s1: Point, s2: Point): Boolean = {
    val d = Haversine.distance(s1.lat, s1.lon, s2.lat, s2.lon)
    val l = Levenshtein.distance(s1.label, s2.label)
    d <= 5.0 && l <= 2
  }
```

I am calling this function many time from within a `while` loop. If I use the `isSimilarFast` version, the program completes in ~37s. If I use `isSimilarSlow`, it takes ~175s, i.e. more than 5 times as long!

Is this because of JVM optimizations for very small functions, or because of Scala compilation issues? How can I investigate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first (fast) implementation the call to `Levenshtein.distance` is only necessary if the first boolean expression evaluates to `true`. If `Haversine.distance > 5.0` there's no need to evaluate the rest, which matches the semantics of `&&`. In the other (slow) implementation the order of the statements requires both invocations to happen, no matter if `d <= 5.0` holds.

Comment: Good point! Not enough coffee :-P  Let me check if that restores sanity.

Comment: Please consider the possibility to upvote/accept good answers :)

Comment: SO tells me I have to wait another 3 minutes before accepting, but I already checked and your answer is 100% correct.

Comment: @mitchus How could you have debugged this? Use a profiler or add a debug statement to the start of each method.